# Attach generated PDF to Email Kohana

Tags: php, email, pdf-generation, kohana, dompdf

I am using the Kohana [PDF Viewer Module](https://github.com/shadowhand/pdfview) (DOMPDF) to dynamically create a PDF file from a HTML page.

I am able to use the Kohana `send_file` to view or download the PDF:

```
// Load a view using the PDF extension
$pdf = View_PDF::factory('Print/Summary');

// Use the PDF as the request response
$response = new Response();
$response->body($pdf);

$filename = 'myfile.pdf';
$response->send_file(TRUE, $filename, array('inline' => TRUE));
```

I would like to attach this PDF to an e-mail and send but I'm unsure what the best way to get this PDF as I would normally use an uploaded file not a server generated one?

Thanks for help with this.

Comment: Who is this guy, Email Kohana? Or she is a girl? Always use glue to attach PDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use swiftmailer to do this: http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html#attaching-dynamic-content

I recommend using Shadowhand's email module which is essentially a wrapper around swiftmailer: https://github.com/shadowhand/email